# Is it safe to truncate ACT_RU_METER_LOG table in Camunda BPM?

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

The ACT_RU_METER_LOG table contains 10 million rows. I want to upgrade the Camunda from 7.10.0 to 7.17 and as part of the upgrade there are few alter table statements on the mentioned table. As expected these alter tables take huge time, hence wondering if I can truncate the table. I am aware that the metrics can be disabled, but the existing data should be cleaned explicitly.

Thanks in advance.